# What does this duration reported by ffmpeg mean?

Tags: time

When I run ffmpeg on an mp4 file, it says the duration is:

```
00:03:57.54
```

What is the unit that `54` represents ? I am interpreting it as 0.0054 seconds (54 milliseconds).

Comment: I'd guess hundreds of a second (otherwise it'd be 00:03:57.0054) so at 26 frames a second that would be 14 frames beyond a full second time

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about about the use and documentation of a given third party tool and not about software design or architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dot in that time representation is a normal decimal point. The `57.54` simply means 57 seconds and 54 hundreds of a second.